# Using facebook connect with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is it possible to use Facebook connect with Jquery? I've
found some old posts saying it isn't possible, but I'm not sure how things
currently are. I've found that the Facebook connect code is mostly
using Fb as the namespace, while jquery uses the `$` sign, so may be it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible to do so.  As long as you aren't making an FBML app, you can use whatever Javascript you'd like.  IFrame apps and Facebook Connect sites are fine.

I have several apps that utilize both MooTools and/or JQuery along with FB Connect with no issues at all.  You are right about the namespacing... Facebook has attempted to isolate their functionality within the `FB` namespace, so there are no longer conflicts with common global functions.

Comment: What do you mean by an 'FBML' app?

Comment: With Facebook, there's generally three types of apps.  **FBML applications** utilize Facebook Markup Language, a super-set of HTML, to render pages through Facebook's servers.  All pages are loaded from the Facebook domain, even though the content comes from your servers.  **Iframe apps** have the content shown in Facebook's canvas layout, but the content is directly requested from your server through an `<iframe>`.  And finally, **Facebook Connect** apps are just integrated external websites that hook into Facebook via their API.

Comment: I should mention also that there are application settings for this (the type of app you want) in the Developer Application control panel.

Comment: Well, the app I'm working on is served through Facebook's servers;
However I'm working on making some pages which are served through my domain, but which mimick the features for the facebook app. Which one do the pages of my website mimicking the actual app qualify for?

Comment: Sounds like a Facebook Connect app, in which case you should be able to use JQuery, as these pages wouldn't be confined inside Facebook's domain.